# Cloning a derived type more elegantly

Tags: c++, templates, clone

I have a pure virtual base class and several derived classes, and I need to clone the derived's.  I did this initially:

```
struct base {
   virtual base* clone() = 0;
}

struct derived: public base {
   base* clone() {
      derived* d = new derived;
      /*copy members, etc.*/
      return d;
   }
}
```

This works fine, except that the clone function implementations in all my derived classes are IDENTICAL except for the returned type (which will be one of the derived types).  In other words, all the operations that I do during the cloning process are common to the base class.  So, the next thing I did was add a template function to my base class:

```
struct base {
   virtual base* clone() = 0;

   template <typename T>
   T* make_clone() {
      T* d = new T;
      /*copy members, etc.*/
      return d;
   }
}

struct derived: public base {
   base* clone() {return base::make_clone<derived>();}
}
```

This works too, but it seems a bit inelegant and I feel like there should be a cleaner approach with fewer function calls and elimination of the one-line functions in all my derived classes.  Is there some language feature or design pattern that I can play with to clean this up a bit?  Also just to clarify, the caller does not know the derived type of the `base*` that it needs to clone.  Otherwise I could just call `base::make_clone<derived>` directly.

Comment: Don't forget a virtual destructor.

Comment: I don't really see the gain against `derived* clone() const override { return new derived(*this); }`

Comment: In my case, there are some subtle but important distinctions between copying and cloning, to the extent that I can't use the copy constructor to clone.  I actually use a different name for my "clone" function so that I remember it's not a true clone in the usual sense of the word.  I just chose to use "clone" in my question because it's very similar to what I'm actually doing and I thought people would understand the question better if I just said "clone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename Derived>
struct derived_base : base
{
    Derived* clone()
    {
        Derived* x = new Derived;
        // ...
        return x;
    }
};

struct derived : derived_base<derived> {}
```

Comment: Function `clone` is `virtual` in the question.

Comment: `clone` returns a pointer to `base` which isn't even a base class of `derived` now.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry. The `virtual` is optional when you derive with the same signature (though I admit it's the better style).

Comment: You should also use co-variant return-types.

Comment: I think filmor just forgot to specify that `derived_base` inherits from `base`.  The answer makes sense if I interpret it that way.  The problem with using the CRTP is that I still need to use pointers to `base`, not `base<derived>`, so I'd need another level of abstraction in there.  This might make the resulting code just as complicated as my current solution.

Comment: @Carlton `clone` member function can be declared as `Derived* clone() { return new Derived; }`. It is a valid C++ and `clone` member function still remains virtual and overrides `virtual base* base::clone() = 0` function.

Comment: @Carlton Would it? If you implement all the cloning in `derived_base` (or, as you did, in a template function of `base`) you just have to derive from that instead of from `base` directly. What more do you want? :)

Comment: Ok, I take back my previous comment.  This was actually very easy to implement and it looks good, too.  Thanks filmor.

Comment: @filmor: about "What more do you want?", I'm missing the `clone()` function in the class that derives from `struct derived`.  Typically `clone()` is used in class hierarchy, but I fear that this solution only works on 1 level, so the class derived from `struct derived` will be sliced to `derived`.

Comment: You could extend the CRTP template such that it would be used on every level of your hierarchy, like `derived2 : derived_base<derived2, derived>` where the second argument defaults to `base`.